# How can I use radar for the obstacle detection?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I use the radar in my local_costmap_params to detect the obstacles? I am displaying data in mm in topic /radar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327074/how-can-i-use-radar-for-the-obstacle-detection?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the costmap configuration part of this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup).
You will need to convert the radar data into LaserScan or PointCloud and then add the sensor under the obstacle_layer in your costmap config files. Should look something like this:

```
point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: frame_name, data_type: PointCloud, topic: topic_name, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0